# Generating triangles from a random set of points

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, geometry

I have randomly generated some points on a JavaScript canvas I was wondering what the most efficient method would be to draw triangles connecting the points in a uniform fashion. The goal is to have the triangles fill the entire canvas without overlapping.

---

For a visual representation, here is an image of the points I have randomly generated across a canvas. As you can see I may have to modify the way I randomly place the points on the canvas.

[image: points]

And this is how I wish to draw the triangles.

[image]

Comment: Consider [Delaunay Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation)

Comment: There's a JavaScript library for that (as always haha): https://github.com/ironwallaby/delaunay

Comment: Thanks @Phrogz, that should be enough to get me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Phorgz & @GabeRogan for pointing me in the right direction. Delaunay Triangulation was definitely the way to go and it ended up being very fast, even when updating the canvas as an animation.

I did end up using the npm package [faster-delaunay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faster-delaunay) which uses the divide and conquer algorithm to triangulate the randomly generated points.

Here is a result of what I have drawn on the canvas that updates as the points move around the plane:

[image: delaunay]